# i tried to make godot 4 car context steering ai using RigidBody3D It's Moving But Not Rotating

Tags: godot, gdscript

i want to make 3d car racing ai using context steer, and follow path3d in godot 4

i tried following kidscancode source code and some ask question how to make context based steering but it's

still not working and also i tried use chatgpt and phind ai and i still not working this code is from phind ai can you fix it or make new script?

the tree nodd: RigidBody3D

the child node : meshinstance, collisionshape3d

here is the script from phind ai:

```
extends RigidBody3D

@export var max_speed = 350
@export var steer_force = 0.1
@export var look_ahead = 100
@export var num_rays = 8

var ray_directions = []
var interest = []
var danger = []
@onready var enemy = get_parent()
var chosen_dir
var velocity = Vector3(0, 0, 0)

func _ready():
    interest.resize(num_rays)
    danger.resize(num_rays)
    ray_directions.resize(num_rays)
    for i in range(num_rays):
        var angle = i *  2 * PI / num_rays
        ray_directions[i] = Vector3.FORWARD.rotated(Vector3.UP, angle)

func set_interest():
    if owner and owner.has_method("get_path_direction"):
        var path_direction = owner.get_path_direction(global_transform.origin)
        for i in range(num_rays):
            var d = ray_directions[i].rotated(Vector3.UP, rotation.y).dot(path_direction)
            interest[i] = max(0, d)
    else:
        set_default_interest()

func set_default_interest():
    for i in range(num_rays):
        var d = ray_directions[i].rotated(Vector3.UP, rotation.y).dot(global_transform.basis.x)
        interest[i] = max(0, d)

func set_danger():
    var space_state = get_world_3d().direct_space_state
    for i in num_rays:
        var query = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(enemy.global_position, global_position * Vector3(0 ,0, 100))
        var result = space_state.intersect_ray(query)
        danger[i] = 1.0 if not result.is_empty() else 0.0

func choose_direction():
    for i in range(num_rays):
        if danger[i] >  0.0:
            interest[i] =  0.0
    chosen_dir = Vector3.ZERO
    for i in range(num_rays):
        chosen_dir += ray_directions[i] * interest[i]
    chosen_dir = chosen_dir.normalized()

func _physics_process(delta):
    set_interest()
    set_danger()
    choose_direction()
    var desired_velocity = chosen_dir * max_speed
    velocity = velocity.lerp(desired_velocity, steer_force * delta)
    look_at(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

Comment: First of all, you have a typo, it is `velocity` not `velocityy`. Second, do not declare your own `velocity` variable (a property is already provided, use it, you can find Q&A about that on this site). I'm voting to close as caused by a typo.

Comment: it's moving now but it can't rotate